# Combining Bash command with AWS CLI copy command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to copy some files from Linux machine to the S3 bucket. I need to copy only selected files. I am able to get files using below Bash command:

```
ls -1t /var/lib/pgsql/backups/full/backup_daily/test* | tail -n +8
```

Now, I want to combine this bash command with AWS S3 [`cp`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command. I searched and find below solution but it's not working.

```
ls -1t /var/lib/pgsql/backups/full/backup_daily/test* | tail -n +8  | aws s3 cp - s3://all-postgresql-backup/dev/
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `man xargs`.

Comment: If that suggestion leads to something like `ls -t | tail | xargs -I% aws s3 cp % s3://...`, it's an error-prone one. Which is to say -- xargs has a place, but needs to be used with care, so just "use xargs" without more warning about how to use it *safely* isn't necessarily good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a platform with GNU tools (`find`, `sort`, `tail`, `sed`), and you want to insert all the names in the position where you have the `-`, doing this reliably (in a manner robust against unexpected filenames) might look like:

```
find /var/lib/pgsql/backups/full/daily_backup -name 'guest*' -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
  sort -znr |
  tail -z -n +8 |
  sed -zEe 's/[^ ]+ //' |
  xargs -0 sh -c 'aws s3 cp "$@" s3://all-postgresql-backup/ncldevshore/' _
```

There's a lot there, so let's take it piece-by-piece:

- `ls` does not generate output safe for programmatic use. Thus, we use `find` instead, with a `-printf` string that puth a timestamp (in UNIX epoch time, seconds since 1970) before each file, and terminates each entry with a NUL (a character which, unlike a newline, cannot exist in filenames on UNIX).
- `sort -z` is a GNU extension which delimits input and output by NULs; `-n` specifies numeric sort (since  the timestamps are numeric); `-r` reverses sort order.
- `sed -z` is a GNU extension which, again, delimits records by NULs rather than newlines; here, we're stripping the timestamp off the records after sorting them.
- `xargs -0 ...` tells `xargs` to read NUL-delimited records from stdin, and append them to the argument list of `...`, splitting into multiple invocations whenever this would go over maximum command-line length.
- `sh -c '..."$@"...' _` runs a shell -- `sh` -- with a command that includes `"$@"`, which expands to the list of arguments that shell was passed. `_` is a placeholder for `$0`. `xargs` will place the names produced by the preceding pipeline after the `_`, becoming `$1`, `$2`, etc, such that they're placed on the `aws` command line in place of the `"$@"`.

---

References:

- [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) - *How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?*
- [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) - *Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`*
- [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) - See the "Actions In Bulk" section for discussion of safety precautions necessary to use `xargs` without introducing bugs (which the above code follows, but other suggestions may not).

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at `S3 sync` and `s3 copy with --exclude` commands.

`aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket --exclude "*.jpg"`

You could have a simple cron job that runs in the background every few minutes and keeps the directories in sync.

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
>   files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates
>   folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: this is one of the solutions to my problem.